# Fill textbox in dockpanel control /w stackpanel - WPF

Tags: .net, wpf

I want the bottom text box to fill the entire form. This is what I have so far, and obviously, pretty stuck. Any ideas?

```
 <DockPanel LastChildFill="True">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <TextBox Name="Textbox1" Controls:TextBoxHelper.ClearTextButton="True" 
                    Controls:TextBoxHelper.Watermark=".Zip file location"
                    IsReadOnly="False" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0"/>
                    <Button Name="openbtn" Content="Open" Width="75" Click="openbtn_click" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0"/>
                    <Button Name="startbtn" Content="Start" Width="75" Click="startbtn_click" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="0"/>
                </Grid>
                <TextBox x:Name="logs"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DockPanel>
```

[image: Picture of issue]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need stack panel because its height is the total heigth of its contained items (then last item cannot fill remaining outer space).

So I suggest You to use the grid to accomplish Your desired behavior:

```
<Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="20"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <TextBox Name="Textbox1" 
                IsReadOnly="False" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0"/>
    <Button Name="openbtn" Content="Open" Width="75" Click="openbtn_click" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0"/>
    <Button Name="startbtn" Content="Start" Width="75" Click="startbtn_click" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="0"/>
    <TextBox x:Name="logs" Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="3"/>
</Grid>
```

Hope it helps

Comment: I had to change the row definitions as it was putting the textbox slightly under the second one, but it worked. Thanks :)

`<RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
<RowDefinition Height="*"/>`